# Possibility to change a font awesome icon with transition

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

No, I have no code to demonstrate but I have been wondering: Is it possible to change a font-awesome logo with just transition? Such as: Change the class? I did a little bit of research on w3schools and [How can create transition effect in font awesome icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34116779/how-can-create-transition-effect-in-font-awesome-icon) found this link aswell, but they didn't really help and this question has been with me for a long time. 
so, the question is: Is it possible to make a logo change (font awesome) with css transition or do I need javascript for it?
in case the question shouldn't be posted here. please tell me where it should so I can move it.

Cheers,

Comment: You will need a javascript for that

Comment: The first line of the first answer of the question you linked says *"Fontawesome transitions could be done like any other CSS transition."*. followed by an example. What else do you need?

Comment: Hi, if what you want to achieve is to animate the shape to change between one icon to an other, I recommand you to look for SVG: https://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/135-three-ways-animate-svg/

Comment: But I am not talking about the font awesome changing of color etc. I mean the font-awesome logo itself completely change. I mean, if that's what I just asked, how come the person above u stated I need javascript? I love the isntant downvote by the way :) Always lovely to see how people are open to some newbie questions

Comment: I didn't get that you actually wanted to change the *shape* of the icon. That's maybe because I didn't read well, but also maybe because you didn't add any attempts, or specific description about what kind of transition you wanted to have. Anyway, maybe you can have a look at [Fontawesome's brand new SVG+Javascript framework](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js), which has the potential of supporting this. You can't just animate font shapes, but you would have way more control over svg shapes, as @Dexter0015 also suggests above..

Comment: the question is: Is it possible to make a logo change (font awesome) with css transition or do I need javascript for it? <- Litterly in my post, but yes, maybe I could've been a bit more specific about it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here you go:

This has been done here: https://codepen.io/toaster99/pen/BpgzQR.

See working example:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: slateblue;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #fe8989;
  border-radius: 2em;
  width: 25.25rem;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  font-size: 2.75rem;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.icons {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 2.3rem 0 0;
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 2.6rem;
}

.icons i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
}

.icon-default {
  transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
}

.icon-hover {
  transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  opacity: 0;
}

.button:hover .icon-hover {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.button:hover .icon-default {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="container">
  <div class="button">
    <div class="icons">
      <i class="fa fa-apple icon-default"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down icon-hover"></i>
    </div>
    Download
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <div class="icons">
      <i class="fa fa-windows icon-default"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up icon-hover"></i>
    </div>
    Request
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, you did the job with the code haha. I can accept ur answer in 4 min. Thank you for the help :) appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

yes, its pretty simple after you see the solution but I was confused too which led me to this post.

css

````css
    @keyframes pulse {
      0% {
        color:transparent;

      }
      50% {
        color: #065803;

      }
      75% {
        color:rgb(113, 139, 0);

      }
      100% {
        color: #065803;

      }
      0% {
        color:rgb(189, 176, 1);

      }
    }

    #linked{
      font-size: 16.5rem;
      color: white;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;

    }
    i{
      animation: pulse 8s infinite ease;

    } ```
````

HTML

````
                       <i id="linked" class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
                      </a>
                    </div>                               
                    <div class="col-2-of-2">
                      <a href="projects.html" target="_blank">
                        <i id="linked" class="fas fa-code"></i>
                      </a>
    ```
````